# Error: NG0301: Export of name 'ngForm' not found

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I am a beginner at angular. I am testing my code using Jasmine but I am getting some errors. I have tried to import everything as per my knowledge. These are the errors that I am facing:

1. Error: NG0301: Export of name 'ngForm' not found!
2. Expected undefined to be truthy.

Also, the code is working fine in the browser in terms of functionality yet I am getting this error in jasmine isolate testing. How can I solve these issues?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

import {FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BookRideComponent } from './book-ride/book-ride.component';
import { SortPipe } from './sort.pipe';
import { CustomPipeComponent } from './custom-pipe/custom-pipe.component';
import { CustpipeComponent } from './custpipe/custpipe.component';
import { RideFilterPipePipe } from './ride-filter-pipe.pipe';
import { ReactFormComponent } from './react-form/react-form.component';
import { TemplateDrivenFormComponent } from './template-driven-form/template-driven-form.component';
import { EmailValidator } from './template-driven-form/emailValidator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    BookRideComponent,
    CustomPipeComponent,
    SortPipe,
    CustpipeComponent,
    RideFilterPipePipe,
    ReactFormComponent,
    TemplateDrivenFormComponent,
    EmailValidator
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule      
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,      
        RouterTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'carpool'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('carpool');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span')?.textContent).toContain('carpool app is running!');
  });
});
```

**template-driven-form.component.html**

```
<div [hidden]="submitted">

<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #courseForm="ngForm" [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="course.courseId" name="id" #id="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="id.valid || id.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>*required</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="course.courseName" name="name" minlength="4" #name="ngModel">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid">
            <div *ngIf="name.errors && name.errors['required']">First Name is required.</div>
            <div *ngIf="name.errors && name.errors['minlength']">First Name is minimum {{ name.errors && name.errors['minlength'].requiredLength }} character.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Duration</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="course.duration" name="duration" #duration="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="duration.valid || duration.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>*required</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
      <!-- <input  type="text"  class="form-control" required ngModel name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" id="firstName">
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="firstName.touched && !firstName.valid">
          <div *ngIf="firstName.errors && firstName.errors['required']">Email is required.</div>
      </div> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="course.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" validateEmail>
        <div *ngIf="email.errors && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p [hidden]="!email.errors['required']">*required</p>
            <p [hidden]="!email.errors['emailInvalid']">{{email.errors['emailInvalid']}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!courseForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="courseForm.reset()">Reset</button>
</form>

</div>
<div [hidden]="!submitted">
    <p>Course ID: {{course.courseId}}</p>
    <p>Course Name: {{course.courseName}}</p>
    <p>Course Duration: {{course.duration}}</p>
    <p>Course Email: {{course.email}}</p>
</div>
```

**template-driven-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { course } from '../course';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-driven-form',
  templateUrl: './template-driven-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template-driven-form.component.css']
})
export class TemplateDrivenFormComponent implements OnInit {

  course: course=new course(1, 'Angular','5 days', 'test@gmail.com');
  submitted=false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted=true;
  }

}
```

**template-driven-form.component.spec.ts***

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TemplateDrivenFormComponent } from './template-driven-form.component';

describe('TemplateDrivenFormComponent', () => {
  let component: TemplateDrivenFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TemplateDrivenFormComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TemplateDrivenFormComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TemplateDrivenFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you have figured it out by now, but in your .spec file you want to add FormsModule to your imports:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ], // <-- here
      declarations: [ TemplateDrivenFormComponent ]
    })
```

Comment: Interesting how this is not mentioned on https://angular.io/errors/NG0301 -- stackoverflow FTW

Answer (score 1):

You have to import reactive forms module configuring in your template-driven-form.component.spec in `configureTestingModule`

You need to import everything you need in each test, so it doesn't matter that reactiveformsmodule is also imported in app.component.spec

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case I had to import ReactiveFormsModule, not FormsModule. So the solution in 'template-driven-form.component.spec.ts' would look like:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...

describe('TemplateDrivenFormComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    ...
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TemplateDrivenFormComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ...
      ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

for me ReactiveFormsModule instead of FormMudule worked just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).